# How can we implement SNN using YOLO v7?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, yolo, yolov7

Please share any ideas or sources which I can refer for the implementation of Spiking Neural Networks using YOLO V7.

I tried implementing the SNN using YOLO V3 by following the GitHub repo : https://github.com/cwq159/PyTorch-Spiking-YOLOv3
Faced some errors though. Now I want implementation using YOLO v7. Any lead is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!